# Unexpected behavior with output formatting for numbers

Tags: output-formatting

In [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EngineeringForm.html) for `EngineeringForm` states:

> prints with all real numbers in *expr* given in engineering notation.

However, if one evaluates the following expression,

```
EngineeringForm[10*10^-3]
```

the result is

> $\frac{1}{100}$

instead of

> $10*10^{-3}$

If a numeric result is forced through use of `N`, the result is given in engineering notation, as expected? A similar behavior occurs with the other output formats for numbers. Could somebody verify this behavior?

```
$Version
```

> 11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67492/discussion-on-question-by-ercegovac-unexpected-behavior-with-output-formatting-f).